# How to check multiple variables for a change and only return those that have changed Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting, react-hooks

I am trying to create a system that checks multiple variables to their original state and only returns the ones that have changes using either javascript or react hooks

It's for checking what changes a user made to a document in firestore
I already have all the code for timestamping when and who made the change, but right now I am just sending all the data again, even if none or very little of the data changed

Pseudocode:

```
let [currentTitle, setCurrentTitle] = usestate("title")
let [oldText, setOldText] = usestate("some text")

let newTitle = "New title"
let newText = "some text"

if  (New variables != Old variables) {
return the new variables that changed and the old variables
}
```

I know that I could just do this,

```
if (newTitle != currentTitle) {
return newTitle, currentTitle
} else if ( newText != oldText ) {
return newText, oldText
}
```

but considering how messy that would be if I had dozens of variables to keep track of having to write out an else if statement for each one would make my code unreadable

I have thought about maybe pushing both into seperate arrays and comparing the two, but again I wouldn't know how to do that with arrays. I may still look into comparing the two arrays and only returning the new item and the old item, but I feel like it may be a better solution to do what I originally thought of doing rather than that. If I am wrong on that front please let me know.

Comment: I'm really wondering why you're doing such a thing.

Comment: Comparing changes in a document, just in case a bad actor changes something and I'd need to revert the changes